# How to display foreign key data value from database to TextBlock on while update form in WPF (MVVM / Entity Framework)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

[OpcUaEndpoint with data](https://photos.app.goo.gl/KYdibF8EL1Ntdw4B9)

Mode, description are displaying in text-block but foreign key value `OpcUaEndpoint` is not being displayed.

What am I missing here? Please help.

Xaml markup:

```
<ItemsControl Name="icName" Margin="10,10,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Scans}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" MouseDown="icName_MouseDown">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="8" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Checkerz" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionLightToggleButton}" Content="{Binding Code}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                <StackPanel Margin="30 0 0 0" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <TextBlock>
                                       <Run Text="Mode: " />
                                          <Run Text="{Binding Mode}" />
                                          <Run Text=", " />
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                          <Run Text="{Binding Scan.OpcUaEndpointRefID}" />
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl> 
Code behind:

        public ControlCenterView()
        {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    var viewmodel = new ScanListViewModel();
                    ScanList.DataContext = viewmodel;
        }

         Modelview

        public DB.model.OpcUaEndpoint OpcUaEndpoint
        {
                    get { return _opcUaEndpoint; }
                    set
                    {
                        _opcUaEndpoint = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("OpcUaEndpoint");
                    }
        }

        public IEnumerable<DB.model.OpcUaEndpoint> OpcUaEndpointsValues
        {
            get { return GetOpcUaEndpoints(); }
        }

        public IEnumerable<DB.model.Scan> ScanValues
        {
            get { return GetScans(); }
        }

        private IList<DB.model.OpcUaEndpoint> GetOpcUaEndpoints()
        {
            _opcUaEndpointsNames = new List<DB.model.OpcUaEndpoint>();

            foreach (var opcpointname in opcUaEndpointsService.GetAll())
            {
                        _opcUaEndpointsNames.Add(opcpointname);
            }

            return _opcUaEndpointsNames;
        }



         //OpcUaEndpoint Model 
             public class OpcUaEndpoint : PlantObject
                {
                    /// <summary>
                    ///     Get or Sets the Identifier.
                    /// </summary>
                    [Key]
                    public int OpcUaEndpointId { get; set; }

                    /// <summary>
                    ///     name of the OpcUaEndpoints.
                    /// </summary>
                    [MaxLength(80)]
                    public string Name { get; set; }

                    /// <summary>
                    ///     OpcUaEndpoint.
                    /// </summary>
                    [MaxLength(255)]
                    public string Endpoint { get; set; }

                    /// <summary>
                    ///     description of the OpcUaEndpoints
                    /// </summary>
                    [MaxLength(255)]
                    public string Description { get; set; }

                    /// <summary>
                    ///UserName of the OpcUaEndpoints
                    /// </summary>
                    [MaxLength(80)]
                    public string Username { get; set; }

                    /// <summary>
                    ///     Password of the OpcUaEndpoints
                    /// </summary>
                    [MaxLength(512)]
                    public string Password { get; set; }

                    /// <summary>
                    ///    RequestTimeout of the OpcUaEndpoints
                    /// </summary>
                    public int RequestTimeout { get; set; }

                    public ICollection<Scan> Scans { get; set; }

                    [NotMapped]
                    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

                    [NotMapped]
                    public string SearchData { get; set; }

                    public override string ToString()
                    {
                        return Name;
                    }
                }

    //Scan Model 
    //its OpcUaEndpointId key to foreign key OpcUaEndpointRefId  in Scan Model.
    //And Scan Is Binded to Item control in Xaml.
     public class Scan : PlantObject
        {

            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }


            public int ScanId { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     name of the scan Mode.
            /// </summary>
            [MaxLength(80)]
            public string Name { get; set; }     


            [MaxLength(255)]
            public string Description { get; set; }



                  public string Code { get; set; }

            **/// <summary>
            ///    Id of the OPC-UA Endpoint for the Scan
            /// </summary>
            [ForeignKey("OpcUaEndpoint")]
            public int OpcUaEndpointRefId { get; set; }**
            /// <summary>
            /// Foreign key to OpcUaEndPoint
            ///
            /// </summary>
            public OpcUaEndpoint OpcUaEndpoint { get; set; }

                   [MaxLength(255)]
            public string DrivingTag { get; set; }

                   [MaxLength(80)]
            public string Operator { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(80)]
            public string Value { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(80)]
            public string DataMode { get; set; }
            [NotMapped]
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

            public bool IsEnable { get; set; }

            public DateTime? StartedOn { get; set; }

            public DateTime? StoppedOn { get; set; }


            [MaxLength(80)]
            public string Status { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code for your OpcUaEndpoint model

Comment: @NeilB posted sir..please find it above.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if your intention is to reference to a property in the OpcUaEndpoint or a property in the view model. I think the problem is that binding directly to an instance of OpcUaEndpoint can't convert to string.

Try this:

```
<Run Text="{Binding OpcUaEndpointRefId}" />
```

Or This:

```
<Run Text="{Binding OpcUaEndpoint.OpcUaEndpointID}" />
```

Comment: Not working sir. i updated my xaml code and scan model. please correct me. if Im missing something there.

Comment: You are trying to bind directly to the OpcUaEndpoint object in the Scan model. You must either bind to a property of the OpcUaEndpoint object, or a property of the Scan model like OpcUaEndpointRefID. What binding error do you see when the project is run? Do you see any text in the run bound to OpcUaEndpoint?

Comment: when i  bind OpcUaEndpoint.OpcUaEndpointId its not showing any error neither any value. And when I bind  <Run Text="{Binding Scan.OpcUaEndpointRefID}" /> its shows  $exception {The runtime refused to evaluate the expression at this time.} System.StackOverflowException. 
What can i do sir then?

Comment: i want to the same in combobox. can you look into code and correct me please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109553/how-to-bind-data-value-to-combobox-on-while-update-form-in-wpf-mvvm

Comment: Sir please find the hyperlink of image above in starting of question. OpcUaEndpoint with data
where OpcUaEndpoint showing data.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I can't see where you set your `OpcUaEndpoint` public property, if you are setting your private field `OnPropertyChanged("OpcUaEndpoint");` won't be reached and it won't be successfully updated. We can't see what are you binding to that `StackPanel`, your `XAML` is missing the best part please update it with the full `Grid` (you can delete private things if you want to).

Show us where you set `OpcUaEndpoint` and be sure you aren't setting `_opcUaEndpoint`.

On the other hand... you are setting a whole entity to the `Run` `Text` property which will cause "problems", you should bind it like this `<Run Text="{Binding OpcUaEndpoint.OpcUaEndpointId }" />`

Comment: Sir, here it is 
public DB.model.OpcUaEndpoint OpcUaEndpoint
    {
                get { return _opcUaEndpoint; }
                set
                {
                    _opcUaEndpoint = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OpcUaEndpoint");
                }
    }
 And I updated My xaml code'
when i bind OpcUaEndpoint.OpcUaEndpointId its not showing any error neither any value. And when I bind <Run Text="{Binding Scan.OpcUaEndpointRefID}" /> its shows $exception {The runtime refused to evaluate the expression at this time.} System.StackOverflowException.

Comment: Sir i want to the same in combobox. can you look into code and correct me please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109553/how-to-bind-data-value-to-combobox-on-while-update-form-in-wpf-mvvm

Comment: I mean, where do you set your `OpcUaEndpoint` ? Where do you do anything similar to this `OpcUaEndpoint = new OpcUaEndpoint()` ? Where do you update your `OpcUaEndpoint` property ?

Comment: No sir. I'm did not set or updated OpcUaEndpoint  Peoperty in my whole code.

Comment: Then how do you expect it to be shown ? If it has no value it won't show anything

Comment: Sir please find the hyperlink of image above in starting of question. OpcUaEndpoint with data where OpcUaEndpoint showing data.